# Why this CSS image preloading solution only works in Chrome and Opera?

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, background-image, preloading

I am trying to make a div's background change every 6 seconds. There are three images which are supposed to rotate and they are all referenced in CSS as background-images associated with a certain class name. The JavasScript rotates the class names on the div every six seconds.

It works in every browser except for one small problem: on the first load of the background images they all flicker. I understand that this can be prevented by pre-loading the images. Yet, I haven't found a solution which works on all "modern browsers" (Chrome, FF; Opera, Edge, Safari).

I have tried adding extra HTML markup with the same background image urls which then I didn't display with css ( `display: none` OR `width: 0; height:0; overflow: hidden`) - only worked in Chrome and Opera.

Then I tried writing a JS function which creates a new Image Object for each of the images and assigns a src attribute to them with `newImg.src="something` this only worked in Chrome too.

I also tried adding a `<link rel="preload>` and a `<link rel="prefetch">` tag to the html head. Both only worked in Chrome and Opera although according to caniuse.com at least prefetch should have worked in Edge and FF too.

My current solution, which still only works in Chrome and Opera is similar to the first one I tried:

```
body::after {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  z-index: -1;
  content: url('imgURL/Img1.jpg') url('imgURL/Img2.jpg') url('ImgURL/Img3.jpg');
}
```

Since this works in Chrome and Opera, I am sure I did not mistype the image URLs. Also, I clear the cache all the time, so it doesn't interfere with how the website appears to work.

The CSS:

```
.first{
  background-image: url('...');
}

.second {
  background-image: url('...');
}

.third {
  background-image: url('...');
}
```

The JS function which is invoked in a setInterval every 6 seconds:

```
function changeImage() {
  const page = document.getElementById('pageId');
  const styleNames = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
  const currentStyle = page.getAttribute('class');
  const nextStyle = styleNames[styleNames.indexOf(currentStyle) + 1];

  if (styleNames.indexOf(currentStyle) === styleNames.length - 1) {
    page.className = styleNames[0];
  } else {
    page.className = nextStyle;
  }
}
```

I would expect at least one of the above solutions to work in all browsers ( ie.: load images without flickering the first time they are displayed), but none worked perfectly and I am out of ideas... Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And element with _zero_ width and height and overflow hidden does not render anything at all. Browsers know that, and therefor some “optimize” in such situations - by not loading images that “no one is ever going to see” in the first place. Make the element 1px by 1px big, and see what results you get then.

Comment: @04FS Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately no change, images still flicker on first load in both FF and Edge.  Chrome and Opera continue to work. Thanks again!